# Loading Header and Footer using HTML Urls in Angular

Tags: angular

I was loading Header and Footer using **External** Html Urls with help of Jquery like

```
$("#dv_header").load(headerUrl);
```

Now how to achieve same in Angular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Angular 2 and above.
Create two components using the angular CLI:

```
ng g c header
ng g c footer
```

Then, in your app.component.ts:

```
<app-header>
<router-outlet>
<app-footer>
```

In your header and footer HTML file, you can either use an iFrame to render the external HTML or in your `header/footer.component.ts` replace:

```
templateUrl: './footer.component.html' (or './header.component.html')
```

with:

```
templateUrl: (YOUR URL HERE)
```

in the `@Component({})` decorator

Comment: the url is external html url,I wrote it like @Component({ selector: 'app-header', // templateUrl: './header.component.html', templateUrl:'abc.html';, styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'] }) and i am getting error Failed to compile. ./src/app/header/header.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'abc.html'; in 'C:\Users\ng_projects\src\app\header

Comment: scratch the external url in `templateUrl`, that didn't work. change it back to `./header.component.html`, and in that file replace `<p>app-header works!</p>` with `<iframe src="externalUrl.com"></iframe>`

Comment: follow this guide: https://www.arka.com/blog/dynamically-generate-angular-components-from-external-html